# change menus item of CSS from C# in WebForms

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

i am working on asp.net web forms where, I have scenario through which I can shown Menus depending on the user rights, but i can find any solution through which I convert css through C# code. [Menu Bar with CSS in ASP .NET](http://www.neerajcodesolutions.com/2014/03/menu-bar-with-css-in-asp-net-c.html) is an example of CSS

is there any other way? if not? then how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Web.sitemap file. Please go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16yk5dby.aspx)